# Using a specific ECDSA curve how can I derive a private key from 2 signatures

Tags: python, ecdsa

I need some help with a little project I'm working on I need to write code that uses this curve:

```
q = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
A = 0
B = 0x07
F = GF(q)
E = EllipticCurve(F,[A,B])
Gx = 0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798
Gy = 0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8
G = E(Gx,Gy)
p = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
assert G.order() == p
```

Then using 2 signatures I need to try and derive the private key.

I've looked up some resources and example code but I can't get my head around using a custom curve.

Thanks in advance

Can't figure this problem out.

Comment: what python library are you using for ecdsa?

Comment: also, the parameters, from memory, look like the curve is Secp256k1, which is a standard curve. So you could just use that

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which library you are using, but here is how to do this with [`fastecdsa`](https://pypi.org/project/fastecdsa/)

Firstly, you need to install the library with `pip install fastecdsa`, but be careful, this library depends on GMP. You'll need GMP installed on your system as the underlying C code in this package includes the gmp.h header. On Fedora Linux, just install `gmp-c++` and `gmp-devel` packages with your favourite package manager.

Now for the actual usage, here is your variables again:

```py
from fastecdsa import curve, keys, ecdsa
from hashlib import sha384

curve_name = "My very own Secp256k1"
p = 0xFFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFE_FFFFFC2F
a = 0
b = 7
q = 0xFFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFE_BAAEDCE6_AF48A03B_BFD25E8C_D0364141
gx = 0x79BE667E_F9DCBBAC_55A06295_CE870B07_029BFCDB_2DCE28D9_59F2815B_16F81798
gy = 0x483ADA77_26A3C465_5DA4FBFC_0E1108A8_FD17B448_A6855419_9C47D08F_FB10D4B8
# oid = THIS IS OPTIONAL
```

To make your own custom curves, you do this:

```py
my_secp256k1 = curve.Curve(
    curve_name,  # (str): The name of the curve
    p,  # (long): The value of p in the curve equation.
    a,  # (long): The value of a in the curve equation.
    b,  # (long): The value of b in the curve equation.
    q,  # (long): The order of the base point of the curve.
    gx,  # (long): The x coordinate of the base point of the curve.
    gy,  # (long): The y coordinate of the base point of the curve.
    # oid  # (str): The object identifier of the curve (optional).
)
```

To generate keys on this curve, you do this:

```py
# generate a keypair
priv_key, pub_key = keys.gen_keypair(my_secp256k1)

# generate a private key for curve P256
priv_key = keys.gen_private_key(my_secp256k1)

# get the public key corresponding to the private key we just generated
pub_key = keys.get_public_key(priv_key, my_secp256k1)
```

To sign and verify messages with ECDSA, you do this:

```py
# some message
message = "a message to sign via ECDSA"

# standard signature, returns two integers
r, s = ecdsa.sign(message, priv_key, curve=my_secp256k1)

# should return True as the signature we just generated is valid.
valid = ecdsa.verify((r, s), message, pub_key, curve=my_secp256k1)

# to specify custom hash function, use optional hashfunc parameter
r, s = ecdsa.sign(message, priv_key, curve=my_secp256k1, hashfunc=sha384)
valid = ecdsa.verify((r, s), message, pub_key, curve=my_secp256k1, hashfunc=sha384)
```

For more usage, refer to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/fastecdsa/).

PS: It looks like you are trying to use the Secp256k1 curve, which is a standard curve. Instead of making your own curve, you could just use `curve.secp256k1`, a pre-defined curve.